# ¿Cómo contar el numero total de registros de 2 campos con SQL?

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla llamada citas, esta tabla esta compuesta de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y otra tabla llamada Areas, que esta compuesta de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es:

Contar con el numero total de registros por Área y por empleado.

Contar cuantos empleados son de cada Área.

**Todo esto, mostrando el nombre del área**

El resultado seria el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el Área **8230**:

**El TOTAL_DE_EMPLEADOS_POR_AREA son 5, porque hay 5 empleado con la misma Área.**

**EL TOTAL_AREA son 5 por que son 5 registros en el campo Área con el mismo numero 8230.**

**El EMPLEADOS_QUE_CAPTURARON Son 3 porque hay 3 empleados que hay con la misma Área.**

Y así sucesivamente con las demás.

Primero quise sacar el total de Áreas que hay pero estoy confundido en como realizar lo demás en la misma consulta. ¿Alguna idea de como realizarlo?.

Esto es lo que llevo:

```
select a.area, a.nombre_area, TOTAL_AREA FROM area A
right join (Select count(area) AS TOTAL_AREA, cec FROM citas
GROUP BY area) AS B
ON A.area = B.area
```

Answer (score 3):

Yo empezaria tu consulta al reves, porque de la tabla area, solo necesitas el nombre, ningun otro dato.

Con lo cual, haria todo sobre citas, y luego le pondria el nombre del area.

la segunda y tercer columna de sumas, parecen la misma, un count(*)... la cuarta, pareceria ser un count(distinc empleado).

Entonces, tu consulta quedaria asi:

```
select area, 
    count(*) as TOTAL_DE_EMPLEADOS_POR_AREA,
    count(*) as TOTAL_AREA ,
    count(distinc empleado) as EMPLEADOS_QUE_CAPTURARON
from citas
group by area
```

Luego, si queres agregar el nombre del area, usa esta consulta como entrada de otra que agregue eso:

```
select *,
    b.nombre_area
from (toda la anterior) a inner join area b
    on a.area = b.area
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder.  Si quiero usar la misma consulta para obtener el nombre, seria con left join como lo estoy haciendo, no?

Comment: la segunda consulta te trae el nombre... para que querrias el left join? @juliofernandez